# Can I deploy a .Net Framework 4.8.2 and a .Net 5 apps in one IIS site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have 2 apps, one is an Asp.Net MVC (In .Net framework 4.8.2) and the other is a Blazor Asp.Net core hosted. For business reasons, the creation of a specific site for the blazor app may be not possible

With this is mind, I got this question, is possible to have 2 apps with that caracterists (.Net 4.8.2 and .Net 5) in the same IIS Site? If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy both .net framework and .net core in the same IIS Site. more information you can refer to this link:

[Configure an ASP.NET Website on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configure-an-asp-net-website-on-iis).

[Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).